# async import() function from CommonJS to load ESM asynchronously:

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, es6-modules, commonjs

I am trying to use one npm package which is ESM
https://www.npmjs.com/package/key-did-resolver

I can not require the 'key-did-resolver' package after installation as it's ESM , So I am trying to load in using async import

The logic I am trying to achieve at the end is as mentioned in the package something like

```
import * as KeyDidResolver from 'key-did-resolver'
import {Resolver} from 'did-resolver'

const keyDidResolver = KeyDIDResolver.getResolver()
console.log(keyDidResolver)
const didResolver = new Resolver(keyDidResolver)
const doc = await didResolver.resolve('did:key:z6MktvqCyLxTsXUH1tUZncNdVeEZ7hNh7npPRbUU27GTrYb8')

console.log(doc)
console.log(doc.didDocument.verificationMethod)
```

So I tried to import on top of my JS class file in my node application as

```
const {Resolver} = require('did-resolver'); // commonJs supported

const didResolve = (...args) => import('key-did-resolver').then(({default: resolver}) => {const didResolver = new Resolver(resolver.getResolver);return  didResolver.resolve(...args) });
```

and in one of the class function I am trying to call it :

```
async myresolve(didKey){
        try {
         await didResolve([didKey]);

        } catch (err) {
          console.error('Error importing key-did-resolver:', err);
        }
}
```

So when I start the server , it's started however when I execute the flow app crashes when it hits " await didResolve([didKey]);"

I'm using node 16

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLo87.png)

How Can I use the loaded package of const didResolve =...etc

Comment: What is the full error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem identification**

`const divResolve` is the **promise object** returned by `then` in the promise chain of its assigned value:

```
const didResolve = (...args) => 
   import('key-did-resolver')
   .then(  ({default: resolver}) => {
                const didResolver = new Resolver(resolver.getResolver);
                return  didResolver.resolve(...args)
    }
);
```

which when fulfilled without error will hold the value that was promised: `didResolver.resolve(...args)`.

**Discussion**

- `await didResolve([didKey]);` should throw a run time error because `didResolve` is not a function.
- As a blanket statement for node: CommonJS modules can't explicitly or implicitly call **any** code imported from an ES6 module, within CommonJS code **run synchronously** at application startup.

**Potential Solutions**

There are two  major approaches to solving the problem if mixed ES6/CommonJS module usage is to be maintained:

1. Put all application code, currently in the main module, into its own application module. Also write a new main (CommonJS) module that loads all ES6 modules, using `import()` and waits for all of them to be loaded before requiring the app module and passing it a single imported value for one module, or  name space object for the default export of multiple ES6 modules.
2. As for 1, but write the main module in ES6 and invoke the application module using [module.createRequire(filename)`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename)